# Twitter-API: Realtime results with low server load/API calls

Tags: php, node.js, twitter, limit

I have a high accessing web service (over 100.000 access per day).
This services loads (among other things) the tweets from a user. Now I have problems with the Rate Limit of the Twitter-API (using REST-API) because of the high access. I cache the tweets but I have more than 350 users (350 API calls per hour).

I heard of [Twitter User Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/user-streams) but I didn't get it. Is there maybe a tutorial/example of using it?

I normally just need to get (at best realtime) the latest/newest tweets of a user (but this with a low server load/API requests). Would node.js be a good solution for that problem? What could you recommend me?

Comment: Why not buy more API calls from twitter - if it's possible?

Comment: It's a free service with no ads and I run/code it in my free time, so this possibility is not really possible ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example nodejs application that uses a twitter stream and server sent events:
https://github.com/chovy/nodejs-stream

Comment: But that seems to work just for one user or if I add a filter param up to 5000 users and Twitter allows just one per stream connection per IP. If I open more I get blacklisted. The problem is that I have more than 5000 users.